# Access denied on folder System32 using cipher command?

Tags: windows-7, encryption

I have not an encyrption software to encrypt the whole harddisk or partition.

It's wrong to think to encrypt the folder System32 gives some security against hackers and malware ?

I tried to run the command as administrator, but the verbose output shows me access denied of all folders and files in C:/windows/system32.

> cipher /E /S:C:\Windows\System32\ /H

Could it be a command syntax error or something else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following items cannot be encrypted:

- Compressed files (using NTFS compression)
- **System files**
- **System directories**
- Root directories
- Transactions

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364223

Comment: Thank you. As written, the access control list seems enough to protect. "Typically, the access control to file and directory objects provided by the Windows security model is sufficient to protect unauthorized access to sensitive information." Except when then laptop is stolen then encryption could be good. So when a malware or hacker gets administrator rights , the encryption may not help. It means that full disk encryption does not encyrpt the mentioned files and folders, nonetheless the disk can't be accessed ?